# How to create "list of type" for HtmlProvider<list of HTML files> in F#?

Tags: f#, type-providers

I am very new to F# and trying to convert my python script to F# code for my learning.

i want to parse multiple (around 25 files) static html files to extract similar information from each file.
I want to have a list of file handle for all the html files.

I am able to do it for single file as:

```
type SummaryHtmlType = HtmlProvider< @"C:/MyLocation/Summary_1.html">
```

I tried something similar to XmlProvider (even not sure if that's correct for XmlProvider), but no success.

```
type MyType = HtmlProvider<htmlFileList; SampleIsList=true>
```

Let me know solution even if there is all together different approach to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"C:/MyLocation/Summary_1.html"` in `type SummaryHtmlType = HtmlProvider< @"C:/MyLocation/Summary_1.html">` is a sample file for HtmlProvider get the basic structure.

To parse file or url, use `Load` method like `SummaryHtmlType.Load(url)`

For more information, see http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/HtmlProvider.html